# saving formatted text in mysql database

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a textarea and I am using WYSIWYG editor so that the users can format the text as they want: changing colors, making bold, changing size etc.. The problem is after I insert the data to the table and retrieve the rows, I don't see the formatting, just plain text. Is there something that I should do when inserting the text not to loose the format? my table `collation` is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Here is the html and I am using ajax to send the form so I don't have name attribute

```
<textarea  id="description" class="jqte-test" ></textarea>
```

The insert query is as below:

```
$desc = trim(strip_tags($_POST["description"]));
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("insert into `test`(`description`) values(?)");
echo $mysqli->error;
$insert->bind_param('s', $desc);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: You are stripping the tags before inserting the text (`strip_tags()`)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is used to strip html/php tags from a value.

I would guess that the WYSIWYG editor you use outputs html data, so by using the strip_tags function you are canceling the formatting.

---

**UPDATE:** when you bind a parameter to a query through pdo it escapes the inserted data.

when inserting the data apply [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)($value, ENT_QUOTES)

and when displaying the data apply [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)($value, ENT_QUOTES)

Comment: thanks however when I retrieve the rows it outputs as `style="font-size:24px;color:
rgb(255, 0, 0);">test` instead of showing the format.